# h2o subset to "bestofFamily"

Tags: h2o, ensemble-learning, automl

AutoML makes two learners, one that includes "all" and the other that is a subset that is "best of family".

Is there any way to not-manually save the components and stacked ensemble aggregator to disk so that that "best of family", treated as a standalone black-box, can be stored, reloaded, and used without requiring literally 1000 less valuable learners to exist in the same space?

If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While running AutoML everything runs in memory (nothing is saved to disk unless you save one of the models to disk - or apply the option of saving an object to disk).

If you just want the "Best of Family" stacked ensemble, all you have to do is [save that binary model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html).  When you save a stacked ensemble, it saves all the required pieces (base models and meta model) for you.  Then you can re-load later for use with another H2O cluster when you're ready to make predictions (just make sure, if you are saving a binary model, that you can use the same version of H2O later on).

Python Example:

```
bestoffamily = h2o.get_model('StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily_0_AutoML_20171121_012135')

h2o.save_model(bestoffamily, path = "/home/users/me/mymodel")
```

R Example:

```
bestoffamily <- h2o.getModel('StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily_0_AutoML_20171121_012135')

h2o.saveModel(bestoffamily, path = "/home/users/me/mymodel")
```

Later on, you re-load the stacked ensemble into memory using `h2o.load_model()` in Python or `h2o.loadModel()` in R.

Alternatively, instead of using an H2O binary model, which requires an H2O cluster to be running at prediction time, you can use a [MOJO model](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html) (different model format).  It's a bit more work to use MOJOs, though they are faster and designed for production use.  If you want to save a MOJO model instead, then you can use `h2o.save_mojo()` in Python or `h2o.saveMojo()` in R.